# Can't pass uri segment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm having a little bit of trouble getting a Laravel 4 route working - just couldn't get my head around it what I'm doing wrong.

My composer packages are up-to-date and I'm using the latest version of illuminate/app.

Here's a route which works fine:

```
GET /hello

Route::get('hello', function()
{
    return 'yey';
});
```

But I just can't get a second uri segment to pass as a param.

This didn't work:

```
GET /hello/1

Route::get('hello/(:num)', function($id)
{
    return 'yey ' . $id;
});
```

Or:

```
GET /hello/1

Route::get('hello/(:any)', function($id)
{
    return 'yey ' . $id;
});
```

Ultimately I want a controller to handle my stuff - but I just don't know what I'm doing wrong at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly. Really you want to be doing this:

```
Route::get('hello/{num}', function($id)
{
    return 'yey ' . $id;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Phil - that's the fix!